# Parsing a string with multiple delimiters in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, delimiter

I'm trying to load a string into an array, removing all whitespace and punctuation.  The problem is, if I have two delimiters in a row, it leaves a blank in the array.

What I have:

```
String[] temparray =inputstr.split("\\s+|,|;|\\(|\\)|, ");
```

Example:

```
inputstr = "I bought bread, eggs, and milk"
```

It outputs as:

```
I
bought
bread

eggs

and
milk
```

Anyone know how to keep the spaces after the commas from being loaded into the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [character class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html) to group all the separator characters

```
String[] temparray = inputstr.split("[\\s,;()]+");
```

Comment: Would you please explain more.

Comment: @mok The `[]` creates a character class consisting of a whitespace character, a comma, a semicolon, and left and right parens. Passing that class to the `split()` method will cause it to split on any of those characters. The `+` following the character class means `1 or more`, so `split()` will split on one or more of the characters. It will split on a single `,`, or one followed by a space like `, `. It will also split on two consecutive commas, or `,; ()`, etc.

Comment: @mok It means that it will use a sequence of _one or more_ of these characters as a delimiter.  This means that if your string is `"I bought bread,, eggs,,;, ;and    milk"`, it returns an array of length 6 `{"I", "bought", "bread", "eggs", "and", "milk"}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the two cases for "comma" and "comma followed by space" by using a `?` metacharacter to indicate "optional".

I've replaced `,` with `, ?` (comma-space-question mark).  This way the space is matched as part of the delimiter.

```
//                           space here ---v
String[] temparray = inputstr.split("\\s+|, ?|;|\\(|\\));
```

Printing each element of the array:

```
I
bought
bread
eggs
and
milk
```